# stumped on jquery call inside chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I call this:

```
jsonPost = {
    email:"phil@demo.demo",
    password:"demo",
    content: $('#selected_text').val(), 
    notification_type: $('#notification_type').val(),
    name:$('#notification_name').val()
}

$.post('http://localhost:3000/api/create.json', jsonPost, 
        function (data) {
            console.log("type of data = " + typeof(data));
            console.log("data in function = " + data);
            }
```

The data makes it to the server.  But the response is lost, in the console 
---type of data = String
---data in function =

So for some reason I am not getting the response back.  Works from the browser.  I even tried doing a get against cnn.com and got no response.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I believe extensions are subject to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in this context, I could be wrong though.  Easy to test, just launch chrome with `chrome.exe --disable-web-security` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running into cross-site-scripting restrictions? If it works in a page that's on "localhost", but not in the extension, it's probably that you need to ask Chrome's permission to access things outside the extension's default security context. See if Google's advice on [requesting cross-origin permissions for an extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) helps.

Comment: it wasn't the ,"json" (which I'd tried).  It was a permissions issue.  In the manifest.json I put this in and it worked: "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/" ],

Actually I wanted http://localhost:3000/ in there, but that didn't seem to work.  But that's just my test env so I don't really care for now...

Answer (score 1):

you need to use json as the post type, for shorthand method, use it like this

```
$.post(url, data, function(result) {

}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will take a "best guess" at how to interpret the data based on the MIME type and some other factors, could it be guessing wrong? You can force it by adding a [fourth parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to your call specifying the data type — e.g., "json", "text", "html"... [Full list here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on the `ajax` docs.