# Will it be possible to create a Chrome extension that uses a PPAPI plugin without a web server?

Tags: plugins, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi

In the tutorial Google provided, they mentioned that you had to use a web server. I want my application to run without an Internet connection. Is this possible?

Comment: You don't need an internet connection to run a web server on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to set up a web server on your machine though. There are free ones on the Internet:

http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS437US437&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=free+web+server&qscrl=1

See this SO question:

[stumped on jquery call inside chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675449/stumped-on-jquery-call-inside-chrome-extension)

...and here is more information from Google:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.proxy.html

...and some problems you might run into:

http://osdir.com/ml/chromium-extensions/2011-05/msg00261.html